# dispay image from array on each buttonclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array, **store**, containing three images. I'm trying to display each image from this array in ascending order on each button click.

ie: first there should not be any image, on first click of the button the first image of the array should load on class `level`.

How can I achieve this?

```js
function store()
{
var level=['https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1','https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2','https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3'];

}
```

```html
<div class="level" style=" width=100px; height:100px; border:2px solid #000;">
<img src="" id="levelimage"  style=" width=100px; height:100px;"/>
</div>

<button onclick="store()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Hey! For people to treat your question more seriously, I suggest adding a quick explanation on how you tried to approach the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load image array and load next images, when clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774824/load-image-array-and-load-next-images-when-clicking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused of what you're asking but I think this will do the trick:

```js
 var i = 0;
 function store() {
  var level = ['https://via.placeholder.com/75x75text=1','https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2','https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3']
  document.querySelector("img").src=level[i++];
  if (i>level.length-1)i=0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="level" style=" width=100px; height:100px; border:2px solid #000;">
  <img src="" id="levelimage"  style=" width=100px; height:100px;"/>
</div>

<button onclick="store()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a global variable i that will stay consistent no matter which function call was it and increase it by one every click, also use DOM to select your img tag and change it's src

```
var i=0;
function store() {
    var level=['https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1','https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2','https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3'];
    document.querySelector(".level").firstChild.src=level[i];
    i+=1;
}
```

Comment: want to display image inside img tag having #levelimage  of class level

Answer (score 0):

```js
// A named function, which expects two arguments:
// e: the Event Object, passed automatically from
//    EventTarget.addEventListener();
// haystack: the array of images.
function imageProgress(e, haystack) {

  // finding the relevant image by navigating the DOM:
  // e.target gives the element that initiated the event,
  // previousElementSibling finds the previous sibling that is
  // an element, Element.querySelector() finds the first (if any)
  // element that matches the supplied CSS selector:
  let target = e.target.previousElementSibling.querySelector('img'),

    // finding the current image:
    currentImage = target.src,

    // finding the index of the current image within the
    // array of images (this returns -1 if the image
    // is not found):
    currentIndex = haystack.indexOf(currentImage);

  // updating the src property of the <img> element;
  // we first increment the currentIndex variable, and
  // divide that updated index by the length of the Array.
  // if there is no current image shown (or the src can't be
  // found in the Array) we start at the first array-index;
  // otherwise we increment through the Array:
  target.src = haystack[++currentIndex % haystack.length];
}
let images = ['https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1', 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2', 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3'],

  // finding the <button> element:
  button = document.querySelector('button');

// using unobtrusive JavaScript to bind the event-handler,
// using an arrow function:
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  imageProgress(e, images)
});
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.level {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: flex;
}

.level img {
  margin: auto;
}

.level,
button {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="level">
  <img src="" id="levelimage" />
</div>

<button>Click me</button>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cj3v2zue/).

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling).

Comment: explains what is need for a starter like me great. thanks alot